# Github - Can't connect to any repository: error occurred during unpacking on the remote end: index-pack abnormal exit)

Tags: github, egit, eclipse-juno

I'm using eclipse Juno and Egit plugin to manage my repo.

I try to push my repo to github to this link, https://github.com/datomnurdin/worklight-mobile

Then I got this error during push to github.

> https://github.com/datomnurdin/worklight-mobile: error occurred during
>   unpacking on the remote end: index-pack abnormal exit

[image]

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just using the `-clean` argument. Thats all.