# Worklight 6.2: Reference Error: WLJQ is not defined

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

My project was working fine before. After I added a few css files and js files from the other project, the preview as common resource or mobilesimulator produced this error. I have tried the suggested methods in this discussion thread (remove the folders in the temp dir, clean the project and reboot). But still could not fix it. Anything special in Worklight 6.2? Thanks.

[IBM Worklight 6.1 - Uncaught ReferenceErrors: WLJQ is not defined, WL is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20606629/ibm-worklight-6-1-uncaught-referenceerrors-wljq-is-not-defined-wl-is-not-def)

Fang

Comment: Edit your question with your index.html

Comment: For some reason, it started working again. I basically gave up on the browser side and built for the environment. Testing in ipad simulator was fine. Later when I found that I need to debug the initial network communication which is not possible with ipad simulator and Safari develop menu, I tried to investigate the browser based testing. Then surprisingly, I found the browser test env is initialized correctly. I didn't do anything significant other than tested a little bit in the ipad simulator. Can't explain what is happening.

Comment: Is there any fixed solution for this. I am facing the same in Mobilefirst 6.3.0 and Environment is MAC. I have to import every time when I close and open the eclipse to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and after working on a app for a while and then closing down eclipse.  On restart I'd often get this problem when working in the browser.  I'd delete the $TMPDIR/wl* folders but with no luck.

I had a tip given to me this weekend which seems to work.

Right click on the common folder within your app in WL Studio and Click Run As > Preview.

It seems if you do this at least once it resolves the problem. Not sure why it works, but it works for me and is much quicker than exporting the project and importing it into another workspace... which also works.

Answer (score 0):

Try to export and re-import the project into a new workspace. I had this issue once, and this helped.

[IBM Worklight 6.1 - Uncaught ReferenceErrors: WLJQ is not defined, WL is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20606629/ibm-worklight-6-1-uncaught-referenceerrors-wljq-is-not-defined-wl-is-not-def)